# NativeScript Sample-Groceries Issue

Tags: angularjs, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When i run the sample app using command `tns run android`, an error is occurred on the console as shown in below image.
[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the platform using `tns platform remove android`, to delete the `node_modules` folder from the project and then to build again  `sample-Groceries` with `tns run android`. However could you give more info about the CLI and modules version and info about the API Level, for which you are trying to deploy your project. Do you try to make clear clone for the project and to build it.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your internet connection that it can not download the dependencies from jcenter.bintray.com maybe it's blocked your country or ... try using vpn.

Comment: Or it firewall but that refused, it's internet thing problem like @HabibKazemi said